# Secure Sign in based on type of employment in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have to create an ADF application in which there is one login page. The login page has two input fields for username and password , one radio button for the type of employee (i.e either employee or manager) and one submit button.

Now depending on the type of user he/she is, one should get redirected to employee or manager page.

For credentials I am using ADF security feature. I have created two users, one for manager role and one for employee role.

I am using Java class for sign in :-

```
package demo.view;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class Login {
private String _username;
private String _password;
private String typeOfEmpl;

public void setUsername(String _username) {
    this._username = _username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return _username;
}

public void setPassword(String _password) {
    this._password = _password;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return _password;
}

public void setTypeOfEmpl(String typeOfEmpl) {
    this.typeOfEmpl = typeOfEmpl;
}

public String getTypeOfEmpl() {
    return typeOfEmpl;
}

public String doLogin() {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (_username == null || _password == null) {
        showError("Invalid credentials", "An incorrect username or password was specified.", null);
    } else {
        ExternalContext ectx = ctx.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            request.login(_username, _password);
            _username = null;
            _password = null;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("success_url", "/faces" + ctx.getViewRoot().getViewId());
            redirect(ectx.getRequestContextPath() + "/adfAuthentication");
        } catch (ServletException fle) {
            showError("ServletException", "Login failed. Please verify the username and password and try again.",
                      null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void redirect(String forwardUrl) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ectx = ctx.getExternalContext();
    try {
        ectx.redirect(forwardUrl);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        showError("IOException", "An error occured during redirecting. Please consult logs for more info.", ie);
    }
}

private void showError(String errType, String message, Exception e) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errType, message);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("d2:it35", msg);
    if (e != null) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This code allows access to only those people who are privileged to the application. But I am unable to relate the radio selection for employee or manager and move to their pages respectively.

How can I correlate both the information(i.e secure sign in and the page that should open on the basis of their employment) and move forward with my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a taskflow router as the start of your page flow to look at the value of the user role and based on it direct to the correct page.
Use EL to access the role used.
More info - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12adf-1364748.html